# Drinking, SO and Copyright Violation

Tags: discussion, fun, copyright-infringement, trademark

Dear MSO users and related staffers...

Recently I have taken to drink to cope with wading through boring SO questions to find some juicy nuggets. Unfortunately, this mix of heavy drinking and SO has resulted in a small Stackoverflow logo following me around:

[image]

Would redistributing such images of myself be deemed copyright/trademark naughty in the official SOTeam™ Opinion?

*( Really, I produce images like this in MSO chat to annotate the mood. Just wondering where the line is).*

Comment: Personally, I'd be more worried about the effect your alcohol consumption is having on the shape of your head.

Comment: Plus, you seem to be drinking so much that you're seeing *ghosts*! (Left hand corner)

Comment: That's a trademark infringement, not copyright infringement.

Comment: "closed as pointless" because he [removed the dots](http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3159/2807838577_83cbed0126_o.jpg?t=1053139) of his picture.

Answer (score 10):

While we're on the topic of Trademark infringement, I'm pretty sure the one I made here is technically illegal going by Stack Overflow branding guidelines:

[image]

Erm... right?

Comment: +1, at least someone realized an actual question was being asked :P